# Elasticsearch: mapping issue with nested element

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm trying to use a mapping for emails. I want to use a nested type for recipients. I tried to use this mapping but i don't understand the elasticsearch issue :

```
{
  "template": "test*",
    "settings":{
     "index":{
        "analysis":{
           "analyzer":{
              "email":{
                 "tokenizer":"keyword",
                 "filter":"lowercase"
              }
           }
        }
     }
  },
  "mappings": {
    "logs": {
      "properties": {
        "@timestamp": {
          "type": "date",
          "format": "strict_date_optional_time||epoch_millis"
        },
        "recipients": {
          "type" : "nested",
          "properties": {
            "rcptto": {"type": "string", "analyzer":"email" }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

When i post my data i got :

```
{
   "error": {
      "root_cause": [
         {
            "type": "illegal_argument_exception",
            "reason": "Mapper for [recipients] conflicts with existing mapping in other types[object mapping [recipients] can't be changed from nested to non-nested]"
         }
      ],
      "type": "illegal_argument_exception",
      "reason": "Mapper for [recipients] conflicts with existing mapping in other types[object mapping [recipients] can't be changed from nested to non-nested]"
   },
   "status": 400
}
```

I take a look closer but i don't understand. When i try to create record into /postfix/foo for exemple, it works but in my mappings i've got :

```
 "mappings": {
    "logs": {
```

Then when i try to create the record in /postfix/logs the recipients.rcptto doesn't exists.

Second thing i don't understand. I deleted postfix*, then i tried to create a record, 1st time it failed (see log below), next same request it worked :'(

```
# curl -XDELETE http://localhost:9200/postfix*
{"acknowledged":true}

# curl -POST http://localhost:9200/postfix/54 -d '
{
                "status" : "sent",
               "queueid" : "3nTgBP6Mrpz18dwD",
         "postfixdaemon" : "smtpd",
            "recipients" : [
            {
                "rcptto" : "misterA@customer.fr"
            }
        ],
              "mailfrom" : "misterB@something.fr",
        "clienthostname" : "server.fr",
                   "pid" : 7996,
                "delays" : "0.06/0/0/0.28",
             "logsource" : "smtp2",
           "total_delay" : 1,
              "mailsize" : 23792,
                 "delay" : 0.34,
               "program" : "postfix",
            "entry_date" : "Jan  5 00:45:33",
             "timestamp" : "Jan  5 00:45:33",
               "removed" : "True",
              "@version" : "1",
            "@timestamp" : "2016-01-04T23:45:33.000Z"
}'
{"error":{"root_cause":[{"type":"illegal_argument_exception","reason":"Mapper for [recipients] conflicts with existing mapping in other types[object mapping [recipients] can't be changed from nested to non-nested]"}],"type":"illegal_argument_exception","reason":"Mapper for [recipients] conflicts with existing mapping in other types[object mapping [recipients] can't be changed from nested to non-nested]"},"status":400}

# curl -POST http://localhost:9200/postfix/54 -d '
{
                "status" : "sent",
               "queueid" : "3nTgBP6Mrpz18dwD",
         "postfixdaemon" : "smtpd",
            "recipients" : [
            {
                "rcptto" : "misterA@customer.fr"
            }
        ],
              "mailfrom" : "misterB@something.fr",
        "clienthostname" : "server.fr",
                   "pid" : 7996,
                "delays" : "0.06/0/0/0.28",
             "logsource" : "smtp2",
           "total_delay" : 1,
              "mailsize" : 23792,
                 "delay" : 0.34,
               "program" : "postfix",
            "entry_date" : "Jan  5 00:45:33",
             "timestamp" : "Jan  5 00:45:33",
               "removed" : "True",
              "@version" : "1",
            "@timestamp" : "2016-01-04T23:45:33.000Z"
}'
{"_index":"postfix","_type":"54","_id":"AVPm6QFs7nZqZ6kMnJ7-","_version":1,"_shards":{"total":2,"successful":1,"failed":0},"created":true}
```

Can you understand this behaviour ?

Elasticsearch logs :

```
[2016-04-05 17:01:45,902][DEBUG][action.admin.indices.mapping.put] [Elastic1.xxxxx] failed to put mappings on indices [[postfix]], type [54]
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Mapper for [recipients] conflicts with existing mapping in other types[object mapping [recipients] can't be changed from nested to non-nested]
```

GET /postfix*/_mapping

```
{
   "postfix": {
      "mappings": {
         "54": {},
         "logs": {
            "properties": {
               "@timestamp": {
                  "type": "date",
                  "format": "strict_date_optional_time||epoch_millis"
               },
               "@version": {
                  "type": "string"
               },
               "clienthostname": {
                  "type": "string"
               },
               "clientip": {
                  "type": "ip"
               },
               "deferred": {
                  "type": "boolean"
               },
               "delay": {
                  "type": "double"
               },
               "delays": {
                  "type": "string"
               },
               "dsn": {
                  "type": "string"
               },
               "entry_date": {
                  "type": "string"
               },
               "lastqueueid": {
                  "type": "string"
               },
               "logsource": {
                  "type": "string"
               },
               "mailfrom": {
                  "type": "string",
                  "index": "not_analyzed"
               },
               "mailsize": {
                  "type": "long"
               },
               "numberofrecipients": {
                  "type": "long"
               },
               "pid": {
                  "type": "long"
               },
               "postfixdaemon": {
                  "type": "string"
               },
               "program": {
                  "type": "string"
               },
               "queueid": {
                  "type": "string"
               },
               "recipients": {
                  "type": "nested",
                  "properties": {
                     "rcptto": {
                        "type": "string",
                        "analyzer": "email"
                     }
                  }
               },
               "relay": {
                  "type": "string"
               },
               "relayip": {
                  "type": "string"
               },
               "removal_time": {
                  "type": "string"
               },
               "removed": {
                  "type": "string"
               },
               "status": {
                  "type": "string"
               },
               "tags": {
                  "type": "string"
               },
               "timestamp": {
                  "type": "string"
               },
               "total_delay": {
                  "type": "long"
               }
            }
         }
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: It seems you already have some mapping which maps recipients to non-nested field. You cannot have same field mapped as two different types across types in the same index. To check if there is already an existing mapping, check curl -XGET 'http://localhost:9200/test/_mapping'

Comment: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/breaking_20_mapping_changes.html#_conflicting_field_mappings


Here it is mentioned that from elastic 2.0 there can't be same field name with two different mapping.

U might want to look into the changes of 2.0.

https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-migration

and to see if your index is compatible with 2.0 or not you can refer to the above link